# Trying to clarify the relationship between JBoss Application Server and Seam:

Tags: jboss, seam, application-server

I am trying to clarify the relationship between JBoss Application Server
and Seam:

1. Is the Seam distribution, or any part of it, included in standard JBoss AS download zip files?
2. If only a part of the Seam distribution is included, which part?
3. If not, is the Seam distribution intended to be downloaded
   separately from http://www.jboss.org/projects and added into the AS?

Thanks

Comment: Please be aware: Tags are not keywords.  `application<space>server` is not the same thing as [tag:application-server].

Answer (score 2):

Seam is not distributed alonside JBoss AS. It is a framework intended to support development of web applications (much like Spring or Struts) and is not tied to JBoss AS in any way (you could use Seam equally well in Glassfish or any other application server, and JBoss AS does not require Seam at all).

Usually, the Seam libraries are part of your own project, among the EAR or WAR libraries. It is to be downloaded separately from [www.seamframework.org](http://www.seamframework.org) or JBoss projects sites and is usually distributed in "runtime" form (you get the seam libraries alongside all dependencies and utility programs, such as `seam-gen` for project generation).